# How do I get my server Ip address for my websocket

Tags: c++, url, websocket, server, ip-address

I've created a server using c++ and crow that uses webSockets to communicate with the client (which is an ionic app). I've been do everything through localhost but now I want to deploy the webapp to my iphone and have it communicate with the server. How do I get the URL for the server for the client to use in it's websocket so it can talk to the server?

Comment: Usually, you would buy a domain name and have you server's IP address published via DNS.

Comment: So I can't communicate with my server unless my IP address is published with DNS?

Comment: Well, you can hard-code the IP address into the app, if you are so inclined. `http://12.34.56.78/` is a valid URL. But usually, you would hard-code the domain name into the app instead, and have it use DNS lookup to find the IP.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but how would I get the URL of my server?

Comment: Are you saying you don't know the IP address of your own server? Well, one way to find out is to browse to https://www.whatismyip.com, assuming you can run a browser on it.

Comment: Okay, I used that and got 156.xx.xx.xx for my public ipv4 and 192.168.xx.xx For my local IP. for my websocket, should i use "ws://192.168.xx.xx/ws"?

Comment: Depends on whether you plan to run your app while connected to the public network or the local network.

Comment: Well I guess I would want to connect to the public network so that I can use the app from a different location. I tried using the public IP so ws://154.xx.xx.xx/ws but the websocket connection didnt work and I got "...WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404". When I kick off my crow server, it says "server running at 0.0.0.0:40060". Would that have anything to do with it? Also, thanks for the help!

Comment: You can try ws://154.xx.xx.xx:40060/ws

Comment: Ah yes... I was missing the port number -_-. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases when you want to host it for production you would upload it to a hosting provider (e.g. Azure, AWS, Heroku...).

Once you set up a server with the hosting provider they will provide you with the IP address and/or a URL to connect to the hosted service which you can use in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your server is like webhost,VPS,CLOUD,or dedicated server, it has static ip address which you can use in your client websocket as the address. Also, the better approach is to point a domain name to the ip address of the server (or host) so that your client can always find the server.

In case you are trying to connect it to your local machine behind a router or modem, then your server might be behind NAT. Find appropriate port-forwarding configuration for your router and forward incoming and outgoing TCP public ports to your local address. then use your public ip address for websocket address ([what is my ip](http://www.whatismyip.com/)).

Also, in case your public ip address is dynamic and might change over time, there are services like [noip.com](http://noip.com) that help you create a free domain and use it in your client which helps you find the right ip address all the time.